# NetBeans new project does not complete

Tags: netbeans-8

I am trying to setup NetBeans 8.2.

I have Java V8 and can get through all of the verification of installation steps on the NetBeans verification page.

All components are present, but the Cygwin installation did not let me select the tested versions of GCC, G++, GDB and make, so I installed the highest versions.

When I try and run through verification with the welcome program (see verifying the installation section of provided link), I see a flash on the screen when I click finish.

I believe the flash is a box that reads **access denied** - its pretty fast so I'm not entirely sure.

I have set all permissions for documents, CYGWIN, JAVA, and NetBeans folders.

I am running Windows 7 on a Dell laptop.

It mostly seems to work, but in the end, the make project wizard does not complete.

I'm not sure if this has to do with incorrect versions or something else.

How would I get the correct CYGWIN versions if required?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/cpp-setup-instructions.html#verifying

```
gcc     4.2.1   GNU C compiler in Mac OS X 10.7 - Installed 7.3.0

g++     4.2.1   GNU C++ compiler in Mac OS X 10.7 - Installed 7.3.0

gdb     6.3.5   GNU debugger in Mac OS X 10.7 - installed 7.12.1-2

make    3.81    GNU make in Mac OS X 10.7 - Installed 4.1

recommended versions
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a permissions problem.  I tried all versions of GCC, G++ etc no effect.  I moved the NB Projects folder from my docs to another folder and it worked fine.